# R: Changing Plot Sizes

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, data-manipulation, decision-tree

I am using the R programming language. I ran a decision tree function using the "rpart" library:

```
library(rpart)
z.auto <- rpart(Mileage ~ Weight, car.test.frame)
```

From here, I tried to plot the results:

```
 plot(z.auto)
```

This returns the following plot:[image]

As well as several warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "use.n" is not a graphical parameter
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "use.n" is not a graphical parameter
3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "use.n" is not a graphical parameter
4: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "use.n" is not a graphical parameter
5: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "use.n" is not a graphical parameter
6: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "use.n" is not a graphical parameter
7: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "use.n" is not a graphical parameter
8: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "use.n" is not a graphical parameter
9: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "use.n" is not a graphical parameter
```

I am trying to add more information this plot (such as the variable names and the decision rules). I did some research and found out that you can add labels to this plot:

```
text(z.auto, use.n=TRUE)
```

This returns the following plot:

[image]

This plot is better - but the text is being cut off towards the bottom. Is there a straightforward way to change the internal size of the plot so that all the text appears without being cut off?

Note: I am using a computer that does not have an internet connection or a USB port - it just has R with some common libraries (e.g. ggplot2, rpart, party, partykit, etc.), I am NOT able to install the "rpart.plot" library on my computer (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart.plot/versions/3.0.9), otherwise I would have tried to use this library instead.

Thank you

Comment: is there way to ensure that the plot is scaled to automatically fit the page? is this problem easier to solve using the libraries "party" or "partykit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xpd=TRUE`. Also `cex=` might be helpful to scale font size.

```
plot(z.auto)
text(z.auto, use.n=TRUE, xpd=TRUE, cex=.8)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply! i cant accept the answer until a few minutes. is it possible to do this as well party? I tried making a plot using the party library and all i got was one big square. Is this also possible with ggplot2? thank you for all your help!

Comment: @stats555 I never used the party library, sorry.

Comment: if possible, can you please take a look at this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679523/r-obtaining-rules-from-a-function thanks you for all your help!

Comment: @stats555 I did, but I'm afraid I have no idea :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rattle` package for plotting of CART like

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(rattle)

z.auto <- rpart(Mileage ~ Weight, car.test.frame)
#Plotting using `rpart.plot` package
prp(z.auto, type = 1)
```

[image]

```
#Plotting using `rattle` package
fancyRpartPlot(z.auto)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As i explained in the question,  unfortunately i do not have access to rpart.plot. i also dont have access to rattle. Can this be done without them? Thanks